# DATETIME Expressions in Hibernate JPQL

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpql

```
Select To_char((( To_timestamp_tz(From_tz(Cast(sysdate AS TIMESTAMP) ,'GMT'))) 
AT TIME ZONE ( 'America/New_York' ) ),'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')  from dual;
```

I wanna execute a SQL similar to the above one, with the sysdate being the column of the tbl i would like to query via Hibernate JPQL.

This is i how i have tried implementing.

```
 Path<Date> comTimePath =  entity.get("SYSDATE");
 Expression<String> com = cb.parameter(String.class,"MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS"); 
 Expression<String> gmt = cb.parameter(String.class,"GMT"); // Parameter value is set as GMT
 Expression<String> est = cb.parameter(String.class,"EST"); // value is set 'America/New_York' 
 Expression<String> fromTzStr = cb.function("From_tz", String.class, comTimePath.as(Timestamp.class),gmt);

 Expression<String> toTimeStamp = cb.function("To_timestamp_tz", String.class, fromTzStr);
 Expression<String> atTimeZone = cb.function("AT TIME ZONE", String.class, est);    
 Expression<String> concat = cb.concat(toTimeStamp, atTimeZone);
 Expression<String> comTimeString= cb.function(TO_CHAR, String.class, concat,com);
```

But the problem is how to add the toTimeStamp & atTimeZone expressions together to form

```
 "To_timestamp_tz(From_tz(Cast(sysdate AS TIMESTAMP) ,'GMT'))) 
  AT TIME ZONE ( 'America/New_York' )".
```

ive tried many functions, but none serve the purpose. Can someone shed light on this one.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: So your problem is how to put `To_timestamp_tz(From_tz(Cast(sysdate AS TIMESTAMP) ,'GMT')))` and `AT TIME ZONE ( 'America/New_York' )` together?

Comment: I don't think that you should make a query against dual with Hibernate because it assumes that tables contain entities with identity. Can't you just use plain SQL?

Comment: Sorry, i had used DUAL in the SQL just for an example. The real implementation im looking for would be like this   
 SELECT * FROM SAMPLETABLE WHERE 
To_char((( To_timestamp_tz(From_tz(Cast(SAMPLETABLE.DATE_COLUMN AS TIMESTAMP) ,'GMT'))) AT TIME ZONE ( 'America/New_York' ) ),'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') like 'MATCH%';      
I wanted to build this SQL using CriteriaBuilder(As shown in the question). But im not able to form the complete query. 
Is there any way this SQL cab be built ?

Comment: You can use Restrictions.sqlRestriction or calculate the time zone in java.